# Up the level of Redis logging

Tags: java, redis, log4j2

I am having an issue where my app is having troubles speaking to Redis.

I want to up the level of logging in Redis to see if it is sturggling with connections but can't work out what category to add to my log4j.

I've tried the above two...

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.modules.redis.RedisConnector" level="DEBUG"/>

    <AsyncLogger name="redis" level="DEBUG"/>
```

But that seems to give me almost nothing. Can someone help me with what logging category i might need to add to see more?

Under the hood my redis code is using the following dependency...

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Please note that my root logger is set to debug. It's not an issue with the log4j config, it's more about trying to find out the right log category and also how to see the Redis/Jedis logs.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package jedis use is `redis.clients.jedis`.

But usually , jedis throws an exception when connecting error, it should work when you config the error log in your own code right. And jedis jar in fact contains very little debug or info logs.

Comment: Thanks. So my second line as per above with 'redis' as the category should take care of it right? i.e. you can specify prefixes.

Comment: @Richie. yes, redis or redis.clients are all ok.